# how does spark executor persist data when it switch to process other partition?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

for example, I have only 1 executor with 4G memory, and 100 partitons.each partition need to process up to 2G data.

I will call map function on the dataframe.In the map function, it will read parquet file from s3 storage, deserialize it into an object(via thrift api), and return the object's member variable(type is bytearray)

finally, I will call `df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(write_path)` to write to another parquet file.

my question is, when executor switch to another partition to run the map function, does it need to 'save' the current partiton data in memory or disk?

I guess it will directly write data to new parquet file instead of save the current partition data, (parquet write is also a map-like function?)

otherwise I have no idea how does it save such huge amount of data(100x2g=200G)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate questions here.

1. when executor switch to another partition to run the map function, does it need to 'save' the current partition data in memory or disk?

The answer is yes. Spark requires a single partition to fit into memory, i.e. when an executor will work on a partition, it will load it entirely. The previously processes partitions will be persisted in memory/disk in volatile format, meaning they will not be available for different transformations (see [cache](https://umbertogriffo.gitbooks.io/apache-spark-best-practices-and-tuning/content/which_storage_level_to_choose.html) to fix it).

2. I guess it will directly write data to new parquet file instead of save the current partition data, (parquet write is also a map-like function?)

The question is not whether parquet is map-like function but is there a **shuffle boundary** between the transformation and the write. They way it works, is that all subsequent transformation which does not require a shuffle form a **stage**, and an executor will run a partition through entire stage every time it is loaded in memory. So, if there is not shuffle boundary between the transformation and the write, every partition will be written separately. This can be easily verified using Spark's [execution graph](https://data-flair.training/blogs/dag-in-apache-spark/) (first hit on Google).

Comment: is there a configuration to specify where to store the processed partitions before loading another partition to process? I have a spark job always throws out OOM exception after processing some partitions, so I guess there might have something to do with these kind of configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Apache spark  action is start run your Spark job, each executor will read few blocks of data (number of blocks will be equal to the number of cores in executor) and process them in parallel.

Apache Spark does not load everything in memory to be able to process it. This is because Spark will partition the data into smaller blocks and operate on these separately when Apache spark reads a file (block by block and distributed over your nodes), process data  mapping in memory and then saves it to storage again.

- https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2014/EECS-2014-12.pdf

Comment: so you mean it still need to save to storage when it switch to process another partition? am I right that the storage can be memory or disk?